# I want to get products by id in Prestashop, and list them

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I want to get products by id in Prestashop, and list them with

```
{include file="$tpl_dir./product-list.tpl" products=$my_products_array}
```

I tried

```
 foreach ($productIds as $key => $productIdsValues) {
        $products2[$key] = get_object_vars(new Product($productIds[$key]));
    }
```

and

```
 foreach ($productIds as $key => $productIdsValues) {
        $products2[$key] = new Product($productIds[$key]);
    }
```

But when i want to list my products, i get error for every products ..

```
Undefined index: price_without_reduction
Undefined index: allow_oosp 
id_product_attribute
```

Original Prestashop 1.6 with original theme, downloaded from te prestashop.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a default `product-list.tpl` you need to create your own SQL query that would get necessary products by their ids. You can peep into `Product.php` and browse methods `getNewProducts`, `getRandomSpecial`, `getPricesDrop` and make something similar or adjust one of them for your needs. I am not saying that it is the only way but in my opinion is the most stable and reliable one

Answer (score 1):

in my case i use `$product=new Product($product_id)` you can also check id be a valid product id by this function :`Validate::isLoadedObject($product_two = new Product($second_product_id))`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers.
I've created a new method for Product class

```
/**
 * Get products by ID
 *
 * @param int $id_lang Language id
 * @param id product
 * @return array New products
 */
public static function getProductById($id_lang,$product_id, $page_number = 0, $nb_products = 10, $count = false, $order_by = null, $order_way = null, Context $context = null)
{

    if (!$context) {
        $context = Context::getContext();
    }

    $front = true;
    if (!in_array($context->controller->controller_type, array('front', 'modulefront'))) {
        $front = false;
    }

    if ($page_number < 0) {
        $page_number = 0;
    }
    if ($nb_products < 1) {
        $nb_products = 10;
    }
    if (empty($order_by) || $order_by == 'position') {
        $order_by = 'date_add';
    }
    if (empty($order_way)) {
        $order_way = 'DESC';
    }
    if ($order_by == 'id_product' || $order_by == 'price' || $order_by == 'date_add' || $order_by == 'date_upd') {
        $order_by_prefix = 'product_shop';
    } elseif ($order_by == 'name') {
        $order_by_prefix = 'pl';
    }
    if (!Validate::isOrderBy($order_by) || !Validate::isOrderWay($order_way)) {
        die(Tools::displayError());
    }

    $sql = new DbQuery();
    $sql->select(
        'p.*, product_shop.*, stock.out_of_stock, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity, pl.`description`, pl.`description_short`, pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`meta_description`,
        pl.`meta_keywords`, pl.`meta_title`, pl.`name`, pl.`available_now`, pl.`available_later`, image_shop.`id_image` id_image, il.`legend`, m.`name` AS manufacturer_name,
        product_shop.`date_add` > "'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.(Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') ? (int)Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') : 20).' DAY')).'" as new'
    );

    $sql->from('product', 'p');
    $sql->join(Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p'));
    $sql->leftJoin('product_lang', 'pl', '
        p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
        AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl')
    );
    $sql->leftJoin('image_shop', 'image_shop', 'image_shop.`id_product` = p.`id_product` AND image_shop.cover=1 AND image_shop.id_shop='.(int)$context->shop->id);
    $sql->leftJoin('image_lang', 'il', 'image_shop.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang);
    $sql->leftJoin('manufacturer', 'm', 'm.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`');

    $sql->where('product_shop.`active` = 1');
    $sql->where('p.`id_product`='.(int)$product_id .' ');

        if (Group::isFeatureActive()) {
        $groups = FrontController::getCurrentCustomerGroups();
        $sql->where('EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp
            JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_group` cg ON (cp.id_category = cg.id_category AND cg.`id_group` '.(count($groups) ? 'IN ('.implode(',', $groups).')' : '= 1').')
            WHERE cp.`id_product` = p.`id_product`)');
    }

    $sql->orderBy((isset($order_by_prefix) ? pSQL($order_by_prefix).'.' : '').'`'.pSQL($order_by).'` '.pSQL($order_way));
    $sql->limit($nb_products, $page_number * $nb_products);

    if (Combination::isFeatureActive()) {
        $sql->select('product_attribute_shop.minimal_quantity AS product_attribute_minimal_quantity, IFNULL(product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute,0) id_product_attribute');
        $sql->leftJoin('product_attribute_shop', 'product_attribute_shop', 'p.`id_product` = product_attribute_shop.`id_product` AND product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1 AND product_attribute_shop.id_shop='.(int)$context->shop->id);
    }
    $sql->join(Product::sqlStock('p', 0));

    $result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql);
    // var_dump($result);die();

    if (!$result) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($order_by == 'price') {
        Tools::orderbyPrice($result, $order_way);
    }

    $products_ids = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $products_ids[] = $row['id_product'];
    }
    // Thus you can avoid one query per product, because there will be only one query for all the products of the cart
    Product::cacheFrontFeatures($products_ids, $id_lang);
    return Product::getProductsProperties((int)$id_lang, $result);
}
```